# Convert only the numeric elements of pd.series to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

```
nome
Douglas Friedrich         custo zero
Ernando                   custo zero
Lucas Fonseca             custo zero
Éverson                           NA
Juninho Capixaba        desconhecido
Zeca                    desconhecido
Nino Paraíba              custo zero
Douglas Borel                     NA
Elton                     custo zero
Ronaldo                   custo zero
Jádson                  desconhecido
Rodriguinho               custo zero
Marco Antônio              120 mil €
Clayson                    880 mil €
Rossi                     custo zero
Gilberto                  custo zero
Saldanha                          NA
Anderson                          NA
Juninho               1.30 milhões €
Wanderson                  400 mil €
Ignácio                 desconhecido
Giovanni                  custo zero
João Pedro              desconhecido
Matheus Silva             custo zero
Gregore                    235 mil €
Flávio                  desconhecido
Yuri                      custo zero
Saldanha                          NA
Danielzinho               custo zero
Alesson                 desconhecido
Élber                      130 mil €
Gustavo                           NA
Fernandão             1.06 milhões €
Name: preco_pago, dtype: object
```

Is there anyway that I can convert only the numeric element of this series to float(ex: `1.30 milhões €`) and leave the rest as it is ? I also would like to convert thousands to 1000 and millions to millions 1000000. This is what I actually want : `1.30 milhões €` to `1300000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have quite complex filtering which does that but, in any case, the dtype within a pandas column is consistent. I'd suggest to filter based on the content, and apply ad-hoc conversion.

So, in order to give a data frame with value being the original one and num being the float one, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = """\
Douglas Friedrich         custo zero
Ernando                   custo zero
Lucas Fonseca             custo zero
Éverson                           NA
Juninho Capixaba        desconhecido
Zeca                    desconhecido
Nino Paraíba              custo zero
Douglas Borel                     NA
Elton                     custo zero
Ronaldo                   custo zero
Jádson                  desconhecido
Rodriguinho               custo zero
Marco Antônio              120 mil €
Clayson                    880 mil €
Rossi                     custo zero
Gilberto                  custo zero
Saldanha                          NA
Anderson                          NA
Juninho               1.30 milhões €
Wanderson                  400 mil €
Ignácio                 desconhecido
Giovanni                  custo zero
João Pedro              desconhecido
Matheus Silva             custo zero
Gregore                    235 mil €
Flávio                  desconhecido
Yuri                      custo zero
Saldanha                          NA
Danielzinho               custo zero
Alesson                 desconhecido
Élber                      130 mil €
Gustavo                           NA
Fernandão             1.06 milhões €"""

data = pd.Series(
    data.split('\n')
).str.replace(
    '  +', '|'
).str.rsplit(
    '|', expand=True
).rename(
    columns=dict(zip(range(2), ['who', 'value']))
)

f = data.value.str.contains('milhões €')
data.loc[f, 'num'] = data.loc[f, 'value'].str.split(' ', 1).str[0].apply(float) * 1000000
f = data.value.str.contains('mil €')
data.loc[f, 'num'] = data.loc[f, 'value'].str.split(' ', 1).str[0].apply(float) * 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have a pandas Series with strings (i.e. your first element is the string `'Douglas Friedrich         custo zero'`.

You'll have to create your own function to parse each string, for example:

```
def convert_to_number(s): 
    n = s.split('  ').strip()  # work with the right-hand portion only 
    if 'milhões' in n: 
        return 1e6 * float(n.split()[0]) 
    if 'mil' in n: 
        return 1e3 * float(n.split()[0]) 
    if 'zero' in n: 
        return 0 
    return np.nan
```

Then simply apply this function to your pandas series:

```
new_series = series.apply(convert_to_number)
```

Of course, you may need to modify the function depending on your needs, or adapt it to any edge cases that may come along.

Comment: I'm sorry, but using apply on a series will call "normal" python with no "numeric optimization" (an apply is more a less a simple loop), so that it can be really slow

Comment: 100% agree, but since OP did not mention any performance requirement, I find using `apply` to be more beginner-friendly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sure, but we’ll, if we have an easy solution, why not taking good habits ? I think that I have a vectorized solution (cf. my post).